# How to fix footer in angular1.5 comps

Tags: angularjs, html, css, footer

I'm creating a application with angular.js 1.5 components. I'm facing a problem with the footer it's going up side rather than staying down how can I fix this?
Here is the plunker code.

```
[https://plnkr.co/edit/ax1EO771NJg1rfgI840S?p=preview][1]
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are using `virtual height` value so the `.wrapper` element takes the height of your window and doesn't push the footer below.

```
.wrapper {
    position: relative;
    top: 0;
    // height: 100vh
}
```

Comment: If I remove the height property It's breaking the sidebar.

Comment: the sidebar is not gonna work either.. if you scroll down the page it will not take the full height of the page. You will need to create a new layout, tried using flexbox.

Comment: No Flexbox I'm using bootstrap.